# Как получить ошибку если ответ от PHP не JSON формат?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Файл index.php

```
<?php
echo 'не json';
?>
```

JS скрипт

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            log('Получение данных...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Успешно');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Ошибка');
        }
    });
```

Сейчас выводит `Успешно`, а нужно чтобы была `Ошибка`

Comment: А $.ajax это jQuery [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? Если так, то выводит "Ошибка". Может вы что-то перепутали?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так(числа тоже считает как JSON)

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            log('Получение данных...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if(isJsonString(data)){
          console.log('Успешно');
          }else{
           console.log('Ошибка');
          }
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Ошибка');
        }
});
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```